# Javascript Promises library to make "long-running-code-non-blocking-UI" in browser?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, nonblocking, promise

### Update

this an update to the question below and should help finding an answer

Taking up the answer from [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo) who also quoted part of the prominent Javascript Promise/A+ definition I want to update the question here.
The [Promise/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) specification suggest in point 2.2.4 this:

> onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution
> context stack contains only platform code. 3.1.

and further explains

> Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise
> implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that
> onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event
> loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack. This can be
> implemented with either a “macro-task” mechanism such as setTimeout or
> setImmediate, or with a “micro-task” mechanism such as
> MutationObserver or process.nextTick. Since the promise implementation
> is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling
> queue or “trampoline” in which the handlers are called.

The very issue I look forward to find with this question is having as the crucial point that Promise implementation Javascript code is itself considered **platform code** and allows to not yield to the eventloop inbetween resolving subsequent promise via calling the `onFulfilled` `onRejected` functions associated. This is good in Node.js(server) as it avoids unnessary relinguishing back to the event-loop (leaving the execution stack), but also causes the challange in a Browser that since the *execution stack* is not exited in between resolving a potentially large number of Promises (which themselves can generate new Promises). Not leaving the execution stack and yielding to the event loop is causing in a Browser the undesired (blocking script warning/problem).
The "trampoline" task-scheduling of the Promise implementation which causes this needs however not necessary refrain from handing back the execution to the Javascript event loop from time to time. Such a feature would allow for using Promises for heavier tasks. Such an implementation for Promises for "long-running-code" is searched/asked for in this question.

Clarification: The "excessive lenght" is not the individual length of the `onFulfilled` function, but the joining together several those functions/callbacks as result of the Promise resolving process (when done in such a "trampoline" way). I am already aware that if one individual `onFulfilled` funciton is too long, this cannot be helped in any way by using any sort of Promise implementation.

The deal here is that the subsequent resolvement of x promises (within one excecution stack and hence without handing back to the Javascript event loop) can provoke an excessive length duration of Javascript code execution. This, when in a Browser is bad (because of blocking).

### The question

In Javascript, `Promises` allow to deal with asynchronous programming tasks. Great!

There are already some implementations and libraries arround [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [WinJS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx) or [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when) to name just a few.
Having looked at then I see that they tackle some of the "special things" in Javascript asynchronous programming challanges.

Normally I perceive them to do this for **promise resolution**

1. Go to the internal list of promises
2. Check if the promise is fullfilled + run all the associated (via `then(onFullfilled,onReject)`) functions.
3. (in some cases we are done here)
4. (in other cases there will be still "pending" promises)

This case (4) is because to have them (the remaining promises) fullfilled would need the current Javascript Code (which is this very code for **promise resolution**) to stop running and allow JS `event loop` to happend (i.e asynchronous things like XHR-requests, or User-UI-interaction). To make this (4) work, the  **promise resolution** normaly schedules a recall (i.e. via setTimeout/setImmediate) and continues after the `event loop` ran and hence maybe some of the "pending" promises have been settled (=rejected/fullfilled).

My worry is that the step 1 and 2 could be runnning for quite a some time, only releasing execution to the `event loop` in case it seems indicated to settle some of the "pending" promises. While "okay" in some cases (i.e. on the server/Node.js) it is quite problematic in a browers, because even though it was no problem to release execution to the `event loop` and have the UI not-blocking, this is not done in the implementations of promises I have seen.

My question therefore is:
Do you know a promise implementation (Javascript Promises library) that cares for the aspect:
*to make "long-running-code-non-blocking-UI" in browser?*

which would mean that the **promise resolution** would voluntarily release execution back to the `event loop` so that CSS animations, user input, mouse interaction, does get enough attention and that there will be no "Warning: Unresponsive script" message.

Comment: What are you talking about? If you are getting "unresponsive script" it's because you have infinite loop or equivalent, that has nothing to do with promises.

Comment: @Esailija I mean it the other way around. "unresponsive script" can be an plain error (infinite loop) OR ALSO it can be a legitimate task which simple is a little bigger. Therefore to avoid one task to be so big we - "devide and conquer" - split it up into parts of the task. This is where the relation to promises is. Because suddenly one synchronously designed task, necessarily (needs to relinguish occasionly to the `even loop` hence becomes asynchrounous of nature. Now Promises could deal with it, but most libraries manage it so that it in effective becomes again 1 big task.Back to start,see?

Comment: No, a library cannot turn your infinite loop or equal into something else from outside.

Comment: @Esailija please not that it is NOT about infinite loops. Believe it or not you can trigger a "unresponsive script" without using an infinite loop. And sure a library can do what I ask for since I have partly already created something. Nonetheless I dislike re-inventing the wheel here. Hence the question. Are you familiar with async. programming in JS , event-loop, "unresponsive script"-warnings. I think this to be a confusing topic after all. Look into/or try `Q` to split-up a big-task via Promises, you'll see it won't work.Yet it could and such a thing could extend the use cases for promises

Comment: @Esailija Would you consider it helpful to have a code example? i.e for a promise split up (hence non-blocking) long-running (yet NOT INFINITE LOOP) kind of code?

Comment: Yes **you** can split your code and use promises/callbacks/generators for the asynchrony. But if you have 1 huge task then nothing is going to split it for you but you. I still don't see how the method of using asynchrony is in anyway related.

Comment: @Esailija The asynchronity aspect comes in here, because of spliting the code (for non-blocking-UI). During handing back to the `event loop` stuff happens, impacting the big tusk. Therefore promises would be a measure to make sure stuff happens in order.

Answer (score 2):

Any compliant promises implementation will not run the `then` functions synchronously, but rather only at the next tick. Therefore, your worry that "step 1 and 2 could be runnning for quite a some time" is unfounded.

From the Promises/A+ spec:

> `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code.
>
> Here "platform code" means engine, environment, and promise implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` execute asynchronously, after the event loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack.

In other words, your formulation under 2) is incorrect. The promises implementation does not "run the associated functions", it *schedules* them.

This cannot help you--indeed there is no way to help you--if a handler itself is "long-running" code.

Comment: thank you @torazaburo , I appreciate your answer! Your explanation is insightful, yet I think you could complement it. At the same source you quoted Promise/A+(http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#notes) it further says `Since the promise implementation is considered platform[...]`. This hits the key of the problem if this question. Because for compliance with Promise/A+ there is not need for yielding via `setTimeout/nextTick` etc. indeed the implementation can call (while continueing its execution stack) to run/resolve the newly then-created without a `setTimeout/nextTick` yielding.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution could be to parse that long-running JavaScript code for example with https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter.

It will make the code be even slower, but you could specify the priority:

```
const myInterpreter = new Interpreter(myCode);
function nextStep() {
    if (myInterpreter.step()) {
        window.setTimeout(nextStep, 100/speed);
    }
}
nextStep();
```